# How to mock async method which is inside a void method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq

I have a void method which is in the view model

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    AsyncMethod01();
    AsyncMethod02();
}
```

Inside that void method there is two async methods are called

```
async void AsyncMethod01()
{
    ServiceResponse<ObservableCollection<User>> response = await 
        Task.Factory.StartNew<ServiceResponse<ObservableCollection<User>>>(UserDetails);
}

async void AsyncMethod02()
{
    ServiceResponse<ObservableCollection<Customer>> response = await
        Task.Factory.StartNew<ServiceResponse<ObservableCollection<Customer>>>(CustDetails);
}
```

So i need to write a unit test to `TestMethod()` using moq

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethodForViewModel()
{
    //Code
}
```

So how to write the unit test for the void `TestMethod()` which include two async methods inside of it. So i need a way to wait till the two async calls are completed in the unit test method.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethodForViewModel()
{
    await AsyncMethod01();
    await AsyncMethod02();
}
```

Comment: Cannot use like that because both methods are private.Only have the access for TestMethod()

Comment: Basically, anything that calls an async method needs to be asynchronous itself.  Change the test method to be async Task.

Comment: Any possible ways to begin from the scratch  ?